# How to fix lxml crash while pip installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, lxml, python-docx

I'm moving from python3.5 to 3.6. I've created a new virtualenv and i'm attempting to install all my packages using a requirements.txt file. However, I'm running into a few problems - especially with lxml. At the moment, the one I'm stumped with is below. Esseentially the installation process stalls at the last line.

Some of the previous problems I faced (lxml wheel not building, blocks of red code) were fixed by installing python3.6-dev. But now I'm having this issue.

```
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./.virtualenvs/legal_subs_3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from protobuf==3.8.0->-r /home/amessios/.virtualenvs/legal_subs_3.6/requirements.txt (line 6)) (41.0.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-wheel-d2dc2cwm
  Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ...   Destination directory: /tmp/pip-wheel-d2dc2cwm
  Running command /home/amessios/.virtualenvs/legal_subs_3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7tkf8ahf/lxml/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-d2dc2cwm --python-tag cp36
  Building lxml version 4.3.3.
  Building without Cython.
  Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml
  copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml
  copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml
  copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml
  copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml
  copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml
  copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml
  copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml
  copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml
  copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/includes
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/html
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/isoschematron
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/isoschematron
  copying src/lxml/etree.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml
  copying src/lxml/etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml
  copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml
  copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml
  copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/includes
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  running build_ext
  building 'lxml.etree' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/src
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/src/lxml
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/home/amessios/.virtualenvs/legal_subs_3.6/include/python3.6m -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/src/lxml/etree.o -w
```

As my packages seemed to be functioning fine in my python3.5.2 virtualenv, they should work fine on 3.6!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! It was just taking ages to do it (without any verbose output). It finished eventually. Leaving the post up in case anyone faces the same problem and starts getting impatient.